# Postfix: sendmail (php-cgi) with different IP as authenticated SMTP Users

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail, smtp

my Postfix-Mail Server is delivering two main types of mails

1. Mail recieved from php-cgi (sendmail), localhost relay
2. Mail recieved from authenticated SASL SMTP Users

Is it possible to define a different IP for each type?

Reason: Prevent that normal Mail can't send mail because of a hacked Web-Site.

My Setup: Postfix & Apache With PHP5-CGI

Comment: Yes. See [postfix multi instance](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix multi instance is a postfix feature that you are looking for. You need two instance.

1. First instance was [null client instance](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html#quick). It will act as system to handle email from PHP apps. Configuration of this instance looks like the describe [in this documentation](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html#quick) except you must add this parameter

   ```
   smtp_bind_address = my.first.ip.address
   ```
2. Second instance was intended to handle email from mail client. In this instance you must add this parameter too

   ```
   smtp_bind_address = my.second.ip.address
   ```

Parameter [smtp_bind_addres](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address)s was  numerical network address that the Postfix SMTP client should bind to when making an IPv4 connection.